# Can't find .pro file for Convert Map Projection?

Tags: idl, idl-programming-language, envi

I'm looking to batch process a convert map projection on a lot of files using IDL and ENVI, but I can't find the .pro file associated with convert map projection. Is it labelled differently? Or should I be using a different .pro file? I'm new to using ENVI and IDL so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already checked this, but have you looked at MAP_SET.PRO and/or MAP_GRID.PRO?  If you have the latitude/longitude coordinates for a set of points to create a map, you should be able to convert between different map projections.  There are also a series of routines called MAP_PROJ_*.PRO that may be of use, but I would need more info to address your question further.